# 質問の内容が英語版SOと重複する場合の引用マナー

Tags: 討議

日本語版スタック・オーバーフローへの質問と同じ内容のものが英語版SOに存在した場合、ユーザーはどのように対処するのが理想的でしょうか？あるいは、回答者が自分の回答の中で英語版SOの内容を引用する場合のマナーにはどんなものが考えられるでしょうか？　いろいろなケースが考えられると思いますが、何らかのガイドラインのようなものがあると混乱を未然に防げるような気がします。

私が思いつくことを箇条書きにします。

- 日本語版SOと英語版SOは別サイトなので、同じ内容の質問が英語版にあっても「重複」にはならない。従って、質問をクローズする必要はない。
- 回答の中で英語版の内容を引用する際は、英語版ページのURLと回答者の名前を記載すること。
- 英語版を引用していることを明記した場合でも、英語版を和訳するだけの回答は推奨しない。引用したコードでも自分自身で動作を検証する必要がある。また、自分の回答へのコメントには責任を持って応答すること。
- 「英語版の内容を引用しました」という回答にUpvoteする場合は、オリジナルの回答にもUpvoteすべき。（？）
- 「英語版に同じ質問がありますよ」とリンクだけを書く行為は推奨しない。（回答ではなくコメント欄ならOK？）

以上、あまりキレイに整理できなくてごめんなさい。皆さまの回答に期待します。

---

**編集** (2014/12/8):

jmacさんとentoに教えていただいた情報を元に追記します。

Stack Exchange blog(英語) に、 "Attribution Required"というタイトルで、このテーマに関連する情報が掲載されています。http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/06/attribution-required/

この記事によるとStack Overflowのコンテンツの知的所有権は、クリエイティブ・コモンズのCC BY-SA 3.0に基づいて提供されています。
https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/3.0/deed.ja

記事のタイトルにも使われている「Attribution(帰属)」という言葉は、クリエイティブ・コモンズて規定されている用語です。

> ライセンスの選択:
>       ・帰属(Attribution)
>       ・非商用(Noncommercial)
>       ・派生作品の禁止(No Derivative Works)
>       ・同様に共有(Share Alike)
>   http://www.hyuki.com/trans/cc-licenses.html より引用。

そして、blogの記事には次のようにあります。

> So let me clarify what we mean by attribution. If you republish this content, we **require** that you:
>
> 1. Visually indicate that the content is from Stack Overflow or the Stack Exchange network in some way. It doesn’t have to be obnoxious; a discreet text blurb is fine.
> 2. Hyperlink directly to the original question on the source site (e.g., http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12345)
> 3. Show the author names for every question and answer
> 4. Hyperlink each author name directly back to their user profile page on the source site (e.g., http://stackoverflow.com/users/12345/username)
>
> By “directly”, I mean each hyperlink must point directly to our domain in standard HTML visible even with JavaScript disabled, and not use a tinyurl or any other form of obfuscation or redirection. Furthermore, the links must not be [nofollowed](http://googleblog.blogspot.jp/2005/01/preventing-comment-spam.html).

英文を直訳します。

> それでは帰属の意味を明確にしましょう。もしあなたがコンテンツを再公表するなら、私たちはあなたに以下のことを**要求**します：
>
> 1. 視覚的にわかるように、そのコンテンツがStack Overflow や the Stack Exchange networkからのものであることを何らかの方法で示すこと。気の滅入るようなやり方でなくて結構です。 "a discreet text blurb"(直訳：配慮されてた宣伝文)でよいです。
> 2. 掲載サイトのオリジナルの質問へ、直接ハイパーリンクすること。　(例、 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12345)
> 3. 全ての質問と回答に関して、著作者の名前(author name)を示すこと。
> 4. それぞれの著作者の名前(author name)の部分は、著作者のユーザープロフィールページへ直接ハイパーリンクすること。　(例、 http://stackoverflow.com/users/12345/username)
>
> 「直接」という言葉の意味することは、それぞれのハイパーリンクが直接私たちのドメインにリンクされており、JavaScriptが無効になっている場合でも標準的なHTMLで見えるようになっている、ということです。また、URLの表示には、tinyurlやその他の不明瞭な形式やリダイレクトを使用しないでください。さらに、リンクを [nofollowed](http://googleblog.blogspot.jp/2005/01/preventing-comment-spam.html)にしないようにしてください。（rel="nofollow"を使用してはいけない）

以上、Stack Exchange blogからからの引用でした。この記事が想定しているのは、SO以外のサイトでSOのコンテンツを再利用するケースだと思われますが、一般的な知的所有権としては、これらの情報を踏まえて考慮する必要があると思われます。

Answer (score 11, accepted):

基本的な考え方として、

- 日本語版SOにとって、英語版SOは別のサイトであり、Wikipediaやブログと同列の参考資料である

  - Wikipediaやブログ記事を引用する時と同じお作法を適用すべし
- 英語版SOのコンテンツはCC-BY-SA 3.0ライセンスで提供されている

を前提に置くと考えを整理しやすいと思います。個々のポイントについて:

> 英語版の質問と重複にする必要はない

賛成です。重複で閉じてしまうと、日本語話者には役にたたないサイトになるから。

> 回答の中で英語版の内容を引用する際は、英語版ページのURLと回答者の名前を記載すること

英語版の引用条件に従うために、少なくとも引用元のURLを記載した方がよいと思います。回答者の名前については、手間がかかるだけで実用的ではないので、記載しなくてもよい、と思います。

質問の補足で引用されているブログ記事の "republish" (複製を他所で公開する) で想定しているのは、サイトごとスクレーピングして広告収入を稼ぐためにクローンを作ったりするようなケースで、日本語版で必要な時に引用するというような場合はゆるいルールでいいのではないかと (勝手ながら) 思います。

> 英語版を引用していることを明記した場合でも、英語版を和訳するだけの回答は推奨しない。引用したコードでも自分自身で動作を検証する必要がある。また、自分の回答へのコメントには責任を持って応答すること。

和訳するだけでなく、**なるべく**自分でも検証した方がよい、と考えます。和訳だけでも役に立つので、時間がなければそこから少しずつ改善していけばよいです。

未検証であれば、未検証だと回答に明記した方が、質問した人に親切です。その回答をみて検証してみた人がコメントで報告してあげれば、後でたどり着いた人の役に立ちます。

自分の回答へのコメントには対応した方がよいのはその通りだと思います。

> 「英語版の内容を引用しました」という回答にUpvoteする場合は、オリジナルの回答にもUpvoteすべき。（？）

引用元をUpvoteする必要はないと思います。理由としては:

- 英語版コミュニティに参加するかどうかは個人の自由である
- ブログ記事の引用をどこかで読んだ時に、元の記事を「いいね」したりするかどうか? と考えると、する人はすればよいし、しない人はしなければよい。これも個人の自由

> 「英語版に同じ質問がありますよ」とリンクだけを書く行為は推奨しない。（回答ではなくコメント欄ならOK？）

賛成です。リンク先の内容を把握しているのであれば、解決方法を回答として投稿し、「このリンクが参考になりそう」というだけであれば質問へのコメントとして追加するのがよいと思います。

みんなの役に立つサイトとしてのクオリティを保つには、Q&A内容を見れば解決方法がわかるようになっているのが理想と考えます。リンク先の回答を回答者が消すかもしれないし、日本語版の中で完結している方が安全安心です。

リンクだけでも役に立ちますが、質問した人への直接の回答になっていないですし、内容を知りたい人がみんなリンク先の内容を解読する必要があります。内容を把握した人が要約を投稿しておけばみんなの時間を節約できます。

コメントで誰かが投稿したリンクを、別の人が回答としてふくらませて投稿するのも遠慮なしにやってよいと思います。

---

編集しました: 引用についての部分を1つにまとめ、箇条書きだった部分を読みやすくしました。

Comment: Wikipediaやブログ記事を引用する時と同じお作法という考え方に賛成です。

Comment: @naota 参考：http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/06/attribution-required/　（英語のみ）

Comment: @jmac ありがおとうございます。教えていただいたblogの記事を読んで、質問を再編集しました。

Answer (score 5):

回答してみて、英語版から引用するとき何に気をつけなければならないのかな、とふと思ったので検索してこのトピックにたどりつきました。

日本の環境由来の質問やエッジの質問であれば、英語版SOから引用しないで独自に回答することになると思いますが、初心者？向けの質問や回答であれば、英語版SOに同じ質問や回答がない、ということはほとんど無いような状況だと思います。

実際、私が先ほど回答したときも英語版のSOを調べて、それらをまとめて回答してみました。
世界のSOという観点からいえば、日本語版・英語版、という区別ではなく、同じ内容であれば、日本語と英語は必ずリンクしているべきなのかなと思います。

なんなら、将来的に英語版SOから引用して翻訳する、ということをSO側でサポートしてもらいたいと思うくらいです。

以下、個別の問題点についての感想です。

- 日本語版SOと英語版SOは別サイトなので、同じ内容の質問が英語版にあっても「重複」にはならない。従って、質問をクローズする必要はない。

  - ないと思います。というかむしろ奨励すべきと思います。
- 回答の中で英語版の内容を引用する際は、英語版ページのURLと回答者の名前を記載すること。

  - 英語版ページのURLがきちんとその回答のURLになっている必要があるのではないでしょうか。英語版回答の左下のshareからコピーすればいいように思います。
  - 回答のURLをはりさえすれば、回答者の情報をコピペする必要はないと思います（SO的な信用度やバッヂなどは表示されないので、何の参考にもならないため。必要ならSOのシステムで自動的に表示すればよい）
- 英語版を引用していることを明記した場合でも、英語版を和訳するだけの回答は推奨しない。引用したコードでも自分自身で動作を検証する必要がある。また、自分の回答へのコメントには責任を持って応答すること。

  - これはその通りと思います。
- 「英語版の内容を引用しました」という回答にUpvoteする場合は、オリジナルの回答にもUpvoteすべき。

  - 検証していれば、自然にupvoteするはずとは思います。
- 「英語版に同じ質問がありますよ」とリンクだけを書く行為は推奨しない。（回答ではなくコメント欄ならOK？）

  - ポインタはものすごく有用な情報なので、そういった回答を妨げず、同じ内容で別の人が投稿してupvoteされればいいかな（自浄作用に任せる）と感じます。

Comment: おっしゃる通り初歩的な質問と回答に関しては、英語版SOでかなりカバーされていますよね。それらの情報にうまくリンクさせるというご意見に賛成です。「share」のURLを使うのはスマートでよいですね。