# 他のサイトでの回答をスタックオーバーフローにコピーすることは推奨されますか

Tags: 討議

他のサイト(具体的にはteratail)での質問に回答しました。
自問自答の形でその回答をスタックオーバーフローにコピーすることは推奨されることでしょうか。

Comment: 「推奨」だと「積極的に行うことが望ましい」という趣旨だと理解するのですが、そういう意図での質問なのでしょうか？ それとも単にライセンス的な面での可・不可を尋ねているのでしょうか？

Comment: 「積極的に行うことが望ましい」かどうかを尋ねています。QAサイトとしてスタックオーバーフロー内で完結した世界を作ることが目的だとすると、できるだけ他のQAサイトの内容も取り込んだほうがいいのかなと考えました。ユーザとしてもいろいろなサイトを探すよりも「このサイトならどんな答えもそろっている」というほうが便利なのかな、と。
あるいは逆に他のサイトにあるQAをここにも置くのは無駄な二重化と考えるのか、といったあたりを念頭に置いて質問しました。
たとえば他のサイトに良い解答があったらコピーではなくそちらに誘導するほうが良いのか、等です。
もちろん、ライセンス的な面での可・不可も気になりますが。

Comment: そのあたりを回答に追記しました。　@holywise さんフォローありがとうございます。

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[自分が既に知っている情報をQ&Aとして投稿するのは問題ありません](https://blog.stackexchange.com/2011/07/its-ok-to-ask-and-answer-your-own-questions/)。それ用の機能もあります。

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

回答のコピーに関してはjmacさんの書かれているとおりです。ただしSOと異なり投稿した内容が CC-BY-SA になるわけではないようですから、他人の質問文を流用するのは避けたほうがいいと思います。

また、既に他サイトでの実績があるからといって、このサイトで難なく受け入れられるとは限りません。オフトピック、あるいは品質が低いと言われるかもしれません。これは英語版 StackOverflow のQ&Aを翻訳して持ってくる場合でも同様です。

単にコピーするのではなく、より簡潔でわかりやすいQ&Aを目指すことを考えてみてください。

---

> 「積極的に行うことが望ましい」かどうかを尋ねています。

なんでもかんでもコピーして質の低いQ&Aが量産されるのは避ける必要があると思いますが、有用な情報であれば、このサイトに投稿することは歓迎されると思います。

> 2008年にStack Overflowが設立された目的は、プログラミングに関する質問の全ての回答をまとめあげ、それらを提供する場を作る事でした。Stack Overflowの誕生以前は、プログラマー自身が自身の貴重な時間を使い、複数のブログ、掲示板やニュースグループで回答を検索した上で、その回答が有効か否かを自分自身でチェックするしかありませんでした。
>   <sub>--- https://blog.stackexchange.com/2014/12/stack-overflow-in-japanese/ より引用</sub>

このサイトであれば、例えば後々になって情報が古くなった場合でも対応が可能です。

- 誰でもそのことをコメントで指摘したり、投稿を修正することができます
- 新しい情報が見つかれば、誰でも追加することができます

個人のブログや、このような機能を持たない掲示板等と比べ、スタックオーバーフローに情報を置く意義はここにあると思います。

> 他のサイトに良い解答があったらコピーではなくそちらに誘導するほうが良いのか

ライセンスの問題はさておき、誘導リンクだけを回答に書くのは避けてください。

> 外部リソースへのリンクは奨励されますが、リンクの前後に文脈がわかる記述を入れ、仲間のユーザーがそのリンクが何で、どうしてそこにあるのかがわかるようにしておきます。リンクできなかったり、リンク先が永久的にオフラインになったりした場合に備えて、重要なリンク先の最も関連性が高い部分を必ず引用してください。
>   <sub>--- https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer より引用</sub>

個人的には、参考リンクは出典やより深く知るためのリソースを提示するためのもので、リンク先がなくとも回答が成立するように、と考えています。

- [質問の内容が英語版SOと重複する場合の引用マナー](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/257/8000)
- [Your answer is in another castle: when is an answer not an answer?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/225370/286934)
- [Are answers that just contain links elsewhere really "good answers"?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8231/286934)

Answer (score 7):

[TeraTailの利用規約](https://teratail.com/legal)では下記が書かれています：

> #### 第9条（権利帰属）
>
> 1. 当社ウェブサイト及び本サービスに関する知的財産権は全て当社または当社にライセンスを許諾している者に帰属しており、本規約に基づく本サービスの利用許諾は、当社ウェブサイトまたは本サービスに関する当社または当社にライセンスを許諾している者の知的財産権の使用許諾を意味するものではありません。
> 2. 登録ユーザーは、投稿データについて、自らが投稿その他送信することについての適法な権利を有していること、及び投稿データが第三者の権利を侵害していないことについて、当社に対し表明し、保証するものとします。
> 3. 登録ユーザーは、投稿データについて、当社に対し、世界的、非独占的、無償、サブライセンス可能かつ譲渡可能な使用、複製、編集、改編、掲載、転載、公衆送信、上映、展示、提供、販売、譲渡、貸与、翻訳、翻案、配布などができる権利および二次的著作物に関する現著作権者の権利（著作権法２１条ないし２８条の権利をいい、商用利用を含む）に関するライセンスを付与します。
> 4. 登録ユーザーは、サイトの質向上・宣伝・利用促進のため、他利用者による投稿内容の編集、メタデータなどへの配信、当社サイト内での掲載、当社が提携しているサイトへの掲載、などを許可するものとします。
> 5. 登録ユーザーは、当社及び当社から権利を承継しまたは許諾された者に対して著作者人格権を行使しないことに同意するものとします。

弁護士ではありませんが、当社の利用規約と同じような条件に見えます。投稿の権限をTeraTailに移していないため、ここでも投稿しても良いと思いますが、念のため、そのサイトと確認したほうがいいです。