# ヘルプセンターに英日翻訳についてのページを追加しましょう

Tags: 討議, 完了, 翻訳, ヘルプ

A lot of thanks to [@nekketsuuu](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/users/19110/nekketsuuu), [@aki](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/users/14055/aki) and [@cubick](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/users/3060/cubick) for the translation!

---

[以前寄せられた回答たちによると](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/2930/78)、日本語版のコミュニティは質問を英語から翻訳することに意義があると考えているようです。それでは、このことについてヘルプセンターに記事を追加すると良いのではないかと思いました。[実はロシア語版 Stack Overflow では全く同じことを行っています](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/translate-from-english)。下にヘルプ内容の提案を書いてみました。これをもとに、文言を変えたり説明を明確化したりして頂けませんか？（例として、[ポルトガル語版 Stack Overflow の記事は全然異なるもののようです](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/7644/17539)）。

---

> ## 英語版サイトの質問や回答を、日本語に翻訳しても良いですか？
>
> **もちろんです！**
>
> 英語版Stack OverflowなどのStack Exchangeのサイトに、役立つ質問や回答があったとしましょう。もしそれが日本語版スタック・オーバーフローにはまだ投稿されておらず、しかも[オントピック](/help/on-topic)な内容であるなら、それを日本語に翻訳して投稿しましょう！
>
> [私たちの大きな目標](/help/manifesto)：
>
> > 検索エンジンにキーワードを入力することで、日本語で詳細に書かれた回答へのリンクが検索結果に表示される環境を整えること。
>
> 翻訳は日本語で利用可能な知識の量を増やし、何千人ものプログラマー仲間が自分たちの問題の解決法を詳細に理解するための手助けとなるでしょう。
>
> #### 翻訳するにあたって、気を付ける点はありますか？
>
> - **翻訳の投稿者は信用度を得ます**。 翻訳された質問は[自己回答の質問](/help/self-answer)と同等となります。この機能を利用して、コミュニティの知識を日本語版スタック・オーバーフローに蓄積してください。
> - **[ライセンスを忘れないでください](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/2940/)**。翻訳元の質問・回答の投稿者への感謝の意として、元々の英語版投稿へリンクしてください。
> - **得意な分野を優先しましょう**。そうすることで翻訳後の文章にも専門用語を適切に散りばめることができ、日本語での検索にひっかかるようにできます。また、その分野への深い理解があれば、翻訳後の投稿に新しい回答やコメント、編集の提案が寄せられても柔軟に対応しやすいです。
> - **量より質を重視しましょう**。 機械翻訳そのままの低品質な翻訳は、他の低品質な投稿と同様に、コミュニティによってクローズまたは削除される場合があります。
> - **臨機応変に**。翻訳する際には、いくつかの回答から最良のものをひとつにまとめ、そして自分の知識をプラスして翻訳を改善することができます。

Comment: To the Community：「質問の分野を考慮しましょう」の部分をもっと上手く書きたいです。今の書き方だとあまり自然な日本語では無いのではないかと感じています。

Comment: To the Community：「質問の分野を考慮しましょう」の部分（現「質問の分野を考えて翻訳しましょう」の部分）を全面的に書き直してみました。いかがでしょうか。

Comment: 別案として「得意な分野で(貢献し|取り組み|優先し)ましょう」

Comment: @cubick さん、ありがとうございます。「得意な分野を優先しましょう」は今のものより自然な日本語だと思います。

Comment: (Sorry for using English) A lot of thanks to everyone who participated! I have added [a new help center article](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/translate-from-english). Please, check it!

Answer (score 3):

### 議論：翻訳版の回答はコミュニティ wiki でなくても良いですか？

[ヘルプの初稿](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/revisions/2934/1)だと "The Author of translations gets a reputation. Translated questions are equivalent to self answered questions." と書かれており、回答も[コミュニティ wiki](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/community-wiki) にせずそのまま投稿してよいように書かれています。

回答の本質的な部分を作る労力を担ったのは自分ではないので、個人的には、翻訳版を自分の回答として投稿するのは違和感がありました。英語版回答を元に独自の日本語版回答を作るという話であれば自分の回答として投稿して良いと思いますが、そのまま翻訳したものを自分の回答として良いものでしょうか。実際今まで私個人は今までコミュニティ wiki として投稿してきました。コミュニティ wiki として回答すると、質問への vote は信用度に関係しますが、回答への vote は信用度に関係しなくなります。

また、コミュニティ wiki として投稿することで、英語版の投稿が書き換わった際に日本語版の投稿を書き換えやすくなるという側面もあります。

**しかし**、回答の妥当性チェックや翻訳にかけた手間を信用度として還元すべきだ、という考え方もあることに気付きました。実際回答の翻訳をするには単なる直訳では不十分で、日本語ネイティブの典型的な環境に照らし合わせて妥当性をチェックし、適切に翻訳する必要があります。過去の議論[「質問の内容が英語版SOと重複する場合の引用マナー」](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/257/19110)では「日本語版SOにとって、英語版SOは別のサイトであり、Wikipediaやブログと同列の参考資料である」という意見も出ており、これに則ると何故翻訳版だけコミュニティ wiki にしないといけないのか疑問が浮かびます。

また、もし英語版の回答が新しい情報によって更新されたのであれば、それにいち早く気づいて新しく別の回答として投稿した人には信用度が与えられるべき、という運用方法もありますし、こちらの方がスタック・オーバーフローの普段のスタイルと合致しています。

#### 質問

今まで日本語版メタでは、「翻訳版はコミュニティ wiki にすべきだ」といった議論は無かったように思います。ですからこれは個人的な違和感を払拭するための提案なのですが、以下の方針でヘルプを書くことにして良いでしょうか？　良ければ upvote で、何かご意見あればコメントでお願いいたします。

- 翻訳版も自分の回答として投稿し、信用度を得て良い。

Comment: +1: 英→日翻訳は単純置換ではないため、翻訳者の貢献は十分評価に値すると考えます。ただ別の懸念として「機械翻訳結果をコピー＆ペースト」されてしまう可能性も考えられます（いくぶん性悪説ですが）。こちらをどう対処すべきかは、実際に起きてしまってからになるでしょうね...

Comment: 失礼しました。質問側に「Quality above quantity. Low quality translations, such as machine translations, like any other low quality posts, can be **closed** and **deleted** by the community.」と明記ありますね。

Answer (score 0):

### 議論：英語以外の言語から翻訳しても良いですか？

このヘルプは英語から日本語に翻訳することをメインとしており、タイトルとしてはそれが分かりやすいと思うのですが、内容としては和訳元を英語に限定しなくても良さそうです。つまり、ロシア語版、スペイン語版、ポルトガル語版など他の多言語版サイトからの翻訳も OK でしょう。

どんな言語からの翻訳でもこのヘルプの対象にすることを前提にヘルプを書くことにしても良いでしょうか？　良ければ upvote で、何かご意見あればコメントでお願いいたします。

Comment: OK/NGで言えば"OK"と思いますが、英語以外のソースでは第三者検証は絶望的な気がしますし（日本語と該当言語のバイリンガルの絶対数が少ないという前提です）、結局は機械翻訳に頼ることになりはしないかと危惧します。機械翻訳結果をパーマネント投稿するくらいならば、その時々の最新技術に任せるほうがマシというスタンスです。

Comment: @yohjp さん、確かにきちんと翻訳になっているかどうかの検証はしにくそうですが、投稿された回答が技術的に良いものかどうかの検証は日本語であれば大抵できるのではないでしょうか。手元で再現できない程度に大きな問題で、正しさを引用元の正しさの帰着するしかない場合が例外になりそうではありますが……。

Comment: 「引用の要件を満たして」「自然な日本語に翻訳されて」いればソースは英語以外からの翻訳も構わないと思いますが、説明として「他言語から」より「英語から」の方が通りがいいというか、すっきりして分かりやすいのかなと個人的に思います。