# 表示が必要 (Attribution Required)

Tags: サポート, stackoverflow.blog, ライセンス

<sup>この投稿は、Stack Overflow Blog ["Attribution Required"](https://stackoverflow.blog/2009/06/25/attribution-required/) ([Jeff Atwood](https://stackoverflow.blog/authors/jeffatwood/)、2009年6月25日) の和訳です。</sup>

---

お互いに共有しリミックスすることを目的に、Stack Overflow やその他の Stack Exchange サイトにおける全てのコンテンツは [cc-wiki](https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/3.0/) (別名 [cc-by-sa](https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/3.0/)) でライセンスされています<sup>†</sup>。また、我々は我々自身で、[全てのデータを便利なデータ・ダンプとして配布しています](https://stackoverflow.blog/2009/06/04/stack-overflow-creative-commons-data-dump/)。

しかし cc-wiki ライセンスは、意図的に寛容なものである一方、**表示 (attribution) を必要としています**。

> **表示** — あなたは 適切なクレジットを表示し、ライセンスへのリンクを提供し、変更があったらその旨を示さなければなりません。あなたはこれらを合理的などのような方法で行っても構いませんが、許諾者があなたやあなたの利用行為を支持していると示唆するような方法は除きます。

私は、この「表示」がどういった意味を持つかは明らかだと思っていました。しかし、インターネットの片隅で Stack Exchange のコンテンツが悪そうな使われ方をしているのを鑑みるに、どうやらそうではないようです：

- http://hiveminds.se/vote/framed/story.php?id=23472 (訳註: リンク切れ)
- http://programmingfaq.w3ec.com/ (訳註: リンク切れ)

(他にもあるかもしれませんが、とりあえず知っているものを挙げました)

そこで、表示とはどういった意味なのかをはっきりさせておこうと思います。もしあなたがコンテンツを再利用しようとしているのであれば、以下のことが**必須**です：

1. 何らかの方法で、**そのコンテンツが Stack Overflow や Stack Exchange network から来たものであると視覚的に示してください**。露骨に強調する必要はありません。短く簡単に書いてあれば良いです。
2. 元のサイトの**元の質問に直接ハイパーリンクしてください**
   (例: http://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/12345)。
3. それぞれの質問と回答で、**著者の名前を示してください**。
4. **それぞれの著者の名前にハイパーリンクを張り**、元のサイト上のユーザー・プロフィール・ページに直接リンクするようにしてください
   (例: http://ja.stackoverflow.com/users/12345/username)。

「直接」というのは、それぞれのハイパーリンクが我々のドメインに向けて直接貼られており、それが標準の HTML において見ることができ、JavaScript を無効化しても大丈夫で、tinyurl やそのほかの難読化やリダイレクトを使わないことを意味します。更に、そのリンクを [nofollowed](https://googleblog.blogspot.com/2005/01/preventing-comment-spam.html) に**しないで**ください。

つまり、公平に表示してくださいということです。サイトに対して表示を行ってください。そしてもっと重要なことに、寛大にもそのコンテンツを最初に作ることに自分の時間を割いてくれた個々人に対して表示を行いましょう。

とにかく、これで混乱が収まることを願います。是非あなたのコンテンツのためにリミックスして再利用してください！　ただし、コンテンツに対して表示する誠実な努力をお願いします。

そしてそのリミックスを新しい職場の可能性にすることを考えてください。今ある[リモートのウェブ開発職](https://stackoverflow.com/jobs/remote-developer-jobs?utm_source=so-owned&utm_medium=blog&utm_campaign=dev-c4al&utm_content=c4al-link)をチェックしてみましょう。

---

†訳註: この記事が投稿されたとき、スタック・オーバーフロー上のコンテンツは CC BY-SA 3.0 でライセンスされていました。しかしその後 [CC BY-SA 4.0 でライセンスされるようになった](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/3080/)ので、現状は少し異なるライセンスが使われています。ただしこの記事に書かれている範囲の内容は変わらないはずです。

<sub>TODO: リンクされている Stack Overflow Blog 記事の和訳</sub>

Comment: 和訳とは別に、このサイトのコンテンツがsa(Share Alike)であることも、もう少し強調したほうが良いかもしれません。