# サイトのライセンスがCC-BY-SA 4.0に変わります

Tags: 討議, ライセンス

今までスタック・オーバーフロー上のコンテンツは Creative Commons Attribution ShareAlike のバージョン 3.0 でライセンスされていましたが、本日あたりからバージョン 4.0 でライセンスされるようになったとのことです。

[Stack Exchange & Stack Overflow Are Moving To CC-BY-SA 4.0](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/333089/341401)

特にこの部分が大事そうです。

> If you have any questions about how licenses may or may not impact your business or personal projects, it's better to speak with your own attorney — we can't provide advice specific enough to be of much use in most cases.
>
> (翻訳) このライセンスがあなたのビジネスや個人製作に影響するかどうか質問があれば、あなたの代理人と相談するのが良いでしょう。多くの場合、我々 SE チームはそれぞれ個別の事情に合わせたアドバイスを提供できません。

スタック・オーバーフロー上で、3.0 と 4.0 の違いに起因する不具合、バグ、翻訳ミスなどありましたら、この投稿へ教えてくださると嬉しいです :)

Comment: 利用規約を変更するのは良いが、変更前の3.0でライセンスされていたコンテンツをSE Teamが4.0でライセンスしなおすことはできるのか？という議論が勃発していました: https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/333094/341401

Comment: バージョンの変更にあたって、利用者目線で気を付けなきゃいけない点がもしあるなら(元のMetaでの)アナウンスで要約をまとめてくれたら親切なのになぁと思ったり。 / MCVEの件もそうだけど、いきなり「変えます」と言うより「変えようと思うけどどうですか？」という手順を踏まないのはなんでだろう。