# 削除された質問を参照するとき、その質問へのURLは帰属として妥当か？

Tags: 討議, ライセンス, 質問の削除

スタック・オーバーフローに投稿された質問や回答は CC BY-SA 4.0 でライセンスされます。CC BY-SA 4.0 では、示されている場合には[適切なクレジットを表示する](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/2940/32986)必要があります。

加えてそれらの投稿は、モデレーターや投稿者が一定の条件で削除できます。さらに、削除された投稿は削除後であっても、信用度が一定以上のユーザーやモデレータなどが閲覧できます。

ここで、削除された投稿を参照することを考えます。すると削除された投稿を閲覧できるユーザーとできないユーザーが生じます。つまりこのような場面では、削除された投稿への URL をクレジットとして記載しても、それが正常に機能しないユーザーがいることになります。

削除された投稿への URL は、帰属の表示として適切なのでしょうか？あるいはこの問題へ対処するための代替がありますか？

Comment: 関連: [How does the Creative Commons license affect deleted content? - MSE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/201609)

Answer (score 2):

CCはライセンシーに元のコンテンツへの到達可能性の担保までは要求していないので、「そのコンテンツに到達できない人がいる」こと自体は問題になりません。単純には書籍を考えてみればわかります。書籍の内容をCCで利用したからといって、第三者が元の本を入手できるかどうかはライセンシーの責任ではありません。

問題は、「削除された投稿」が依然としてCCで利用可能な状態かどうかです。質問は「利用可能な状態にある」という前提でされていますがこれは自明ではありません。一方で、「削除」=「CCによる利用許諾の終了」といえるかどうかも自明ではありません。さらに言うとこちらは仮にSOがそう言っていたとしても元の投稿者によるCCに基づく利用許諾まで終了したと見なせるかという点も問題になります。

(「ライセンス」という言葉が「条件」と「許諾した/されたという事実」の両方の意味があり誤解につながるので編集しました)

以下議論のために

## 「削除された投稿」はどういう状態か

質問にあるとおり「信用度が一定以上のユーザーやモデレータ」は閲覧できる状態です。ただし「削除された投稿」である旨が記載されています。フッタには「ユーザーの投稿はcc by-saでライセンスされます」という記載が通常と同様に表示されています。

### 一部の人にしか見えないことがCCによる利用許諾に影響するか

「削除された投稿を参照するのは不適切」というのは感覚的には同意できるのですが根拠がないのであればライセンス上どうあるべきかという話にはかえって有害です。

例えば会員制のサイトであってもコンテンツがCCで利用許諾されていれば会員しか見えないことを持って利用が制限されるようなことはないはずです。

### 「削除された」という表記はCCによる利用許諾に影響するか

単にこの表記だけでCCによる利用許諾から外れた、と言うのはさすがにこじつけだと思います

## 個人的な整理

上記の内容だけであれば削除された投稿であっても引き続きCCで利用可能である、であれば冒頭記載の通りたとえそれがリンク切れになる人がいたとしてもURLは表示として妥当、といえるかなと思います。

ただし、そもそも利用規約のどっかに書いてあるとか、別のポイントの解釈によって、「利用可能な状態」が否定される可能性は十分にあります。

## CCによる利用許諾の取り消し、終了について

(mjyさんの回答へのコメントの転載に一部加筆)

CCの条文にある「取り消すことができない」とか「終了しません」というのは、「CCに基づく利用を後から無効にすることができない」ようにするためのもので、今回の例では「削除前された投稿の利用」は削除によって影響を受けないことはこれらによって保証されています。

ライセンス条件が変更されたり公開が終了されたものについて、それ以降に新たに変更前の条件で利用できることまでは保証していないように考えます。

よって、これらの条文は「削除された投稿が依然としてCCとして利用可能か」には影響しないと思います。

削除された(またはライセンス条件が変更された)コンテンツについては、「「以前のCCによる利用」のCCによる利用」のパターンがありますがこちらは問題なく利用可能です。

Answer (score 2):

#### 妥当と考えます

CCで利用可能な投稿ならば、削除された投稿のURLであっても、CCにおける「表示」として妥当と考えます。理由はsuzukisさんの回答と同じです。

では、そもそも、

> 「削除された投稿」が依然としてCCで利用可能な状態か

という論点が suzukis さんの回答に含まれていますので、その点に関して以下に意見を述べます。

#### 削除された投稿も依然として CC BY-SA である

削除された投稿もCCでライセンスされた状態が継続しており、第三者がCCで利用可能だと考えます。

##### 1. CCに基づいて許可された権利は取消されない

根拠は下に示すCCの条文です。

> ...
> ライセンスする方のための留意事項：
> クリエイティブ・コモンズのパブリック・ライセンスは、著作権その他一定の権利により制限されている方法によるマテリアルの利用を公衆に対して許諾する権限を持つ方によって使われることを意図しています。**【クリエイティブ・コモンズのライセンスは取消すことができません。】**
>
> ...
>
> 第6条　期間および終了
> ...
> c. 誤解を避けるために記すと、許諾者は、いつでも、別の条項の下でライセンス対象物を提供したり、**【ライセンス対象物の配布を停止することができます。しかし、その場合でも、本パブリック・ライセンスは終了しません。】**
> ...
>
> —— [クリエイティブ・コモンズ 表示-継承 4.0 国際 パブリック・ライセンス](https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/4.0/legalcode.ja)より（`【 】`による強調は私によるものです）

##### 2. StackOverflowはCCに基づいて投稿の利用を投稿者から許可されている

根拠は下に示す利用規約の条文です。

> Subscriber Content
>
> You agree that any and all content, including without limitation any and all text, graphics, logos, tools, photographs, images, illustrations, software or source code, audio and video, animations, and product feedback (collectively, “Content”) that you provide to the public Network (collectively, “Subscriber Content”), is perpetually and **【irrevocably】** licensed to Stack Overflow on a worldwide, royalty-free, non-exclusive **【basis pursuant to Creative Commons licensing terms (CC BY-SA 4.0)】**, and you grant Stack Overflow the perpetual and irrevocable right and license to access, use, process, copy, distribute, export, display and to commercially exploit such Subscriber Content, 【**even if such Subscriber Content has been contributed and subsequently removed by you**】 as reasonably necessary to, for example (without limitation):
> ...
> This means that **【you cannot revoke permission】** for Stack Overflow to publish, distribute, store and use such content and to allow others to have derivative rights to publish, distribute, store and use such content.
> ...
>
> —— [Public Network Terms of Service / 6. Content Permissions, Restrictions, and Creative Commons Licensing](https://stackoverflow.com/legal/terms-of-service#licensing) より（`【 】`による強調は私によるものです）

##### 3. StackOverflowは削除された投稿をCCに基づいて利用（保存・公開）している

下は[私が自分で削除した投稿のタイムライン](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/posts/41379/timeline)ですが、現在のライセンスが投稿時と変わらずCC BY-SA 3.0 であるとされています。これは投稿本文と同じく、一部の権限のあるユーザーにしか閲覧できませんが、その事とライセンスには関係がありません。（仮に、CCに基づかない勝手なライセンスを表示してしまうと、StackOverflowがCCライセンスに違反することになります）

> [image: 削除された投稿のタイムライン]

##### 4. よって、削除された投稿はCCであり、CCに基づいて利用できる

- **削除前に投稿を利用していた場合:** これは上記『1. CCに基づいて許可された権利は取消されない』により、変わることなくCCによる利用を続けられます。
- **削除後に閲覧権限のある人物が投稿を閲覧し、利用したいと考えた場合:** これがもっとも議論のある所と思いますが、上記『3. StackOverflowは削除された投稿をCCに基づいて利用（保存・公開）している』から考えると、閲覧した投稿はCCであり、CCに基づいた利用が許可されます。

---

以下は補足です。

#### 「表示」してはいけない場合がある

URLや投稿の作者のユーザー名などは、「表示」することが求められますが、それらの「表示」を止めるように作者から求められた場合は、従わなければいけません。根拠は下に示すCCの条文です。
もちろん、その場合は、まずはStackOverflow社の責任において、投稿の該当箇所が消されているはずです。（URLに関しては、「投稿から投稿のURLを削除する」というのは奇妙で実現不可能な気もするので、「合理的に実施可能な範囲」からはずれるかも知れません）

> 第3条　ライセンス利用条件
>
> ライセンスされた権利をあなたが行使するにあたっては、以下に記載された諸条件に従う必要があります。
>
> a. 表示
> ...
> 　3. **【許諾者からリクエストされれば、あなたは第3条(a)(1)(A)に掲げるいかなる情報も合理的に実施可能な範囲で削除しなければなりません。】**
> ...
>
> —— [クリエイティブ・コモンズ 表示-継承 4.0 国際 パブリック・ライセンス](https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/4.0/legalcode.ja)より（`【 】`による強調は私によるものです）

Comment: 「取り消すことができない」とか「終了しません」というのは、「CCに基づく利用を後から無効にすることができない」ようにするためのもので、今回の例では「削除前された投稿の利用」は削除によって影響を受けないことはこれらによって保証されています。ライセンス条件が変更されたり公開が終了されたものについて、それ以降に新たに変更前の条件で利用できることまでは保証していないように考えます。もう一つ、「「以前のCCによる利用」のCCによる利用」のパターンがありますがこちらは問題なく利用可能です。

Comment: 私は削除された投稿が「利用可能である」とも「利用可能でない」とも主張していないので、その点は修正いただけませんか。

Comment: @suzukis  さんが『「利用可能である」とも「利用可能でない」とも主張していない』ことは理解しているつもりです。
どちらも「自明とは言えない」というご意見ですよね。
私も自明とまでは言えないと思います。
よって「〜と考えます」という形で意見を表明いたしました。
通常の意見交換と思うのですが、修正が必要な箇所はどこですか？
論調が断定的すぎましたでしょうか？

Comment: 「URLが表示として妥当」というのはCCでの利用を前提としたものなので、私の回答を「理由」とされてしまうと私の回答も「利用可能」という趣旨と解釈されているのかと思いました。そうではないということなので、mjyさんとしては削除された投稿もCCに基づき利用可能であると考えられている(ここは私の回答は無関係)、その場合の表示としてURLを用いるのは妥当でありその理由は私の回答(の特に1段落目)、という意図だと言うことであっていますか？

Comment: @suzukis そのような意図でした。ご指摘を受け読み返すと、意図が伝わらない文章になっていたようで、ご迷惑をかけました。とりあえず、気付いた点を修正しました。

Answer (score 0):

URL はあくまで補助的な情報に過ぎないので、元のページを参照せずとも (あなたの) 投稿を見れば内容が把握できるようになっているのが理想だと思います。

ですので、必要な部分を適切に "引用" してあなたの投稿に含めてください。

**関連ヘルプ:**
[他の人が書いた資料を参照する方法](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/referencing)

そうする事で、スタックオーバーフローのコンテンツかどうかに関わらず、リンク切れ等で参照できなくなった時にも投稿の価値が失われずに済みます。

---

**追記:**

(一定の信用度で) 削除された投稿が参照できるのは、主に「その削除が妥当であるかを判断するため」であり、"削除の取り消し" などで議論する場合を除いて基本的には "存在しない" 投稿として扱うべきです。

参照しようとした時点で既に「(正当な理由で) 削除された投稿」であるなら参照するのは **不適当** ですし、逆に「価値ある投稿が正当な理由無く削除された」状態なら、まず "削除の取り消し" を検討すべきだと思います。

Comment: 回答の趣旨には同意します。一方でCC BY-SAライセンスそのものの話題として、「一定の信用度をもつユーザー以外が閲覧できないコンテンツへのリンク」は適切な帰属とみなせるのか、という点を本質問ではお聞きしたいです。

Comment: 削除された投稿について「 "存在しない" 投稿として扱うべき」「参照するのは 不適当」という根拠は何でしょうか。例えば「削除された時点でCC-BYによるライセンスは終了する」という定めがありますか。

Comment: お答えいただけないのでしょうか。モデレーターによるライセンスに関連する根拠に基づかない発言が残っているのはまずいと思うのですが。

Comment: 私の回答は「投稿の削除に伴ってライセンスの扱いが変わる」といった趣旨の発言ではありません。また、削除された投稿の URL は (権限がなければ) 基本的に 404 エラーが返されますし、削除されたものを "存在しない" ものとして扱わないと削除の意味が無いですよね？これもライセンスとは離れた一般的な話です。(権限があれば見えるけど、その使い方は回答中で述べた通りです) / 「削除されていることが事前にわかった上で引用するとしたら…」という視点に対しての回答を行ったつもりですが、質問の前提で求めていたものとは少しずれていたかもしれません。 / また、(コミュニティ) モデレーターといえど法律やライセンスの専門家ではない点は予めご了承下さい。

Comment: 質問は一貫してライセンスの話なのですから、ライセンスに関する趣旨の発言ではないとかライセンスとは離れた一般的な話と言われるのは支離滅裂です。

Comment: 質問の趣旨とは全く無関係な回答と言うことでしたら誤解を招かないよう明記するなり削除するなりされたらどうでしょうか。間違って+投票された方もいるようなので。